# Не работает justify-content-end в navbar-nav

Tags: bootstrap

Не могу выровнять пункты меню в навигационном баре по правому краю

В теге navbar-nav не работает justify-content-end

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Seibur</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
        <li class="navbar-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли дивы container и row, я вставляю  justify-content-center в row

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```